# Prevent delete data

Tags: liferay

I make two entity (UserProfile and UserProfileView) in service.xml in portlet and deploy  this portlet in application server.
then create these  tables in database .
Then I got a drop table  and create view instead of table. this view create from other table .
(Create View UserProfileView 
 As 
   select * 
   from UserProfile )

Now when I start the server error that I can not drop the view UserProfileView , then delete all data records in the table and view.
What can be done to fix this problem?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to define your requirement. Can you please elaborate it further and provide log traces.

Comment: What does this sense? "then create these tables in database". Is service.xml not creating tables automatically?

Comment: I think not creating table with service.xml . when deploy portlet and start   tomcat bundle liferay , create table in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent this, we must set this value in service.properties portlet:

> build.auto.upgrade=false